# How do I interpret a shared domain of two functions?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the two given functions with the given domains:

$\mathscr{D}_f:x \in \mathbb{R}  \backslash \{-1\leqslant x\leqslant1\};y  \in \mathbb{R}  \backslash \{\pm1\} $,  not on the curve $ y>\pm\sqrt{1 - x^2}$  and not on the line $x+y>0$. $\mathscr{D}_v:x \in \mathbb{R}; y \in \mathbb{R}$, not on the parabola $y=-x^2$.

Then I am looking for partial derivatives of *f* and  *v* with values of x that belong to a sector of the domains defined by $\mathscr{D}_f\cap\mathscr{D}_v$. Can I therefore conclude that $\mathscr{D}_f\cap\mathscr{D}_v$ is the same as (following above):

$x \in \mathbb{R}  \backslash \{-1\leqslant x\leqslant1\};y  \in \mathbb{R}  \backslash \{\pm1\} $,  not on the curve $ y>\pm\sqrt{1 - x^2}$  and not on the line $x+y>0$

?

All help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

*So all elements of the domain of $f$ which are common with the domain of $v$.*